# How to setup PHP along Ruby on Rails Apache

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

Currently I have Apache Webserver running Ruby on Rails. This is config of Rails:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /app/htdocs/

    <Directory "/app/htdocs">
        Options MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.html
   </Directory>

   RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'http'
   ProxyPass /bs-web http://127.0.0.1:4909/bs-web
   ProxyPassReverse /bs-web http://127.0.0.1:4909/bs-web

</VirtualHost>
```

But now I want to run PHP on this server. I added this config to httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:4910>
    DocumentRoot "/app/gstation"
    <Directory "/app/gstation">
        Options -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #RailsEnv production
        #Order allow,deny
        #Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it's not working. I cannot call to port 4910.

How can I add PHP site to this web server ???

Comment: so u want rails app on the main domain and php on sub domain

Comment: Rails app currently run like this: http://ip-address/bs-web. Now I want PHP app run as well as http://ip-address/gstation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Listen directive in your httpd.conf. There should be a line saying `Listen 80`, change this to `Listen 80,4910` and restart apache.

If this is a remote server and the above doesn't do the trick, also share the output of `iptables --list` with us and check any other firewalls in between (also on the client side).

**Update**: I suppose you have some kind of server for your Rails app running on port 4909 and are proxying to it (when running Apache, [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) might also be something to look at, by the way). If you want to run the PHP app in the other subdirectory, you could simply put the app in the folder `/app/htdocs/gstation` or make use of the [Alias Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias). If you put the following below your proxy definition, it should work:

```
Alias /gstation /app/gstation
```

However, now you will have your app running on port 80, so if you want to run it on port 4910, you would also have to add `*:4910` to your Virtualhost opening tag. I doubt that's what you're looking for though, if I understand your comment correctly.

Comment: I already added listen directive to my httpd.conf. I want PHP site to be like this http://ip-address/gstation. How can I do that ?

Answer (score -1):

To deploy multiple rails app websites on the same instance, use railsbaseuri and create symlinks in that folder to point to your rails application public folder

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain_name.com
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/vol/
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/vol>
        Allow from all
        </Directory>


        RailsBaseURI /rails-app1
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/vol/rails-app1>
        Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

create a symlink for the rails app in vol folder.

```
    ln -s /home/ubuntu/rails_project_folder/public rails-app1
```

Keep the php application inside vol folder and it should work with /php-app-name on the domain. Though i have not tested it but this is what my understanding says. Come back if any issues..